# How do I create dynamic variable names inside a loop in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like

```
month  dest
1       a
1       bb
2       cc 
2       dd
3       ee
4       bb
```

I need to create a set to 4 another dataframe. I am looping over and hope to assign name of dataframe dynamicall inside loop, like

```
i=1
while i<=4:

    dataframe+str(i)=org_dataframe.loc[org_dataframe['month'] == i]
    i=i+1
```

It gives me,

> SyntaxError: can't assign to operator

how do I create a dynamic string variable/name of dataframe.

Answer (score 6):

I think the best is create `dict` of objects - see [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/2901002)

You can use `dict` of `DataFrames` by converting [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) object to `dict`:

```
d = dict(tuple(df.groupby('month')))
print (d)
{1:    month dest
0      1    a
1      1   bb, 2:    month dest
2      2   cc
3      2   dd, 3:    month dest
4      3   ee, 4:    month dest
5      4   bb}

print (d[1])
   month dest
0      1    a
1      1   bb
```

Another solution:

```
for i, x in df.groupby('month'):
    globals()['dataframe' + str(i)] = x

print (dataframe1)
   month dest
0      1    a
1      1   bb
```

Comment: Looking to use this in something similar - but my month is a datetime 2020-03-01 and so on. Struggling to see what my created dataframe will be called as print (dataframe2020-03-01) give me an error. Thanks. But that suggestion below solves that....should've read on.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list of dataframes:

```
dataframe = []
dataframe.append(None)

group = org_dataframe.groupby('month')

for n,g in group:
    dataframe.append(g)

dataframe[1]
```

Output:

```
   month dest
0      1    a
1      1   bb

dataframe[2]
```

Output:

```
   month dest
2      2   cc
3      2   dd
```

Comment: I am curiuous, what is your avatar? ATM?

Comment: @jezrael The college I attended here in United States.  Texas A&M University which logo looks like [aTm](https://www.tamu.edu/).